# Where (and how) to put PDB files for custom .NET code?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

Our developer sent me a PDB file to help debug a custom application. I currently have my symbol directory set to c:\symbols, and several Microsoft symbols are there in this folder format:

ntdll.pdb
        | -----GUID
                  | ----> ntdll.pdb

If the developer gave me a PDB named LL.SharePoint.Portal.pdb, how would I correctly place it into my symbol store? What value should be used for the GUID?

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool, `symstore.exe`, which is included in the debugging tools for Windows package.  It will file symbols in the correct directory tree format. You would use:

```
symstore.exe add -t SharePoint -s c:\symbols -f c:\current\path\to\symbol\LL.SharePoint.Portal.pdb
```

Where:
-t is the product name (this can be anything)
-s is the path to the root of your symbol store directory
-f is a path to the symbol files you want to add to your symbol cache.

Aside from `add`, there is also a `del` and `query` verb. Use `/?` to see how to use the other options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just get away with putting it in the same folder as the (offending) DLL.

Comment: In addition, you may find there are more people with windbg knowledge on stackoverflow.com